# WP Query paging not generating

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a seemingly simple WP query looking for posts on my site, and want these posts to be 'paged' accordingly. Below is my code, trying to achieve this, however all I am currently seeing is an empty .pager nav.

What is incorrect here? Help much appreciated.

[Here is the live example.](http://staging.kurdmemory.com/journal/)

**PHP**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <main>
    <?php
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }

    $custom_query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'journal', 
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date'
    );
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

            <article>
                /* Article content here */
            </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php if ($custom_query->max_num_pages > 1) : // custom pagination  ?>
        <nav class="pager">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'prev_next'          => true,
                'show_all'           => true,
                'type'               => 'list'
            );
            echo paginate_links( $args );
            ?>
            <ul class="page-prev-next">
                <?php if( get_previous_posts_link() ) :
                    echo '<li class="prev-page">' . get_previous_posts_link( 'Prev' ) . '</li>';
                endif; ?>
                <?php if( get_next_posts_link() ) :
                    echo '<li class="next-page">' . get_next_posts_link( 'Next' ) . '</li>';
                endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: It just works, only your links don't seem visible, don't know what's wrong with that. But you can test your pagination by setting the `$_GET['page']` variable: http://staging.kurdmemory.com/journal/?page=2 As you can see it shows different posts, and a "prev" link

Comment: Thanks @ErikvandeVen. The Prev link on display actually just links to the same page though? Any ideas why I can't see pagination on the first page, struggling to find a troubleshooting start point!